# How to change the page content based on Carousel in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, carousel

I am a newbie to ionic framework and I am using the carousel from this link "http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-create-elegant-slider-carousel-in-ionic-framework/".

I have to change the content of page according to the slides of carousel.

Comment: You should elaborate with what your trying ruchi :) @Ruchi

Comment: for example in carousel i have 3 images i.e., new, delete, update. Now on the basis of the main images (which is in the middle) say "new", i want to change the content of the page

Comment: You need to bind the data with your carousel say onclick() in js..Something like that.I dnt know much about Ionic so Can't demonstrate you But I have same for Angular..Can I?

Comment: yes... please.. may be it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, may be it would help you :)

```
<div id="miniMizedCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                             <div id="textViewer" class="fluidMedia">
                                               <div ng-switch-when="VIDEO" ng-class="{'marBot45':fullScreen==true}">
                                                    <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
                                                    <div xyz-video videocode="videoCode">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="quizViewer" ng-switch-when="QUIZ" ng-bind="lessonContent">
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="Div2" class="fsContentArea" ng-switch-when="TEXT" ng-bind="lessonContent">
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="htmlViewer" class="lessonContentArea" ng-switch-when="HTML" ng-bind-html="lessonContent">
                                                </div>
                                                <div ng-switch-when="HTMLACTIVITY" ng-class="{'marBot45':fullScreen==true}">
                                                    <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
                                                    <iframe id="htmlActivity" ng-src="{{lessonContent}}">
                                                    </iframe>
                                                 </div>
                                                <div ng-switch-when="PDF" ng-class="{'marBot45':fullScreen==true}">
                                                    <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
                                                    <iframe id="pdfViewer" ng-src="{{lessonContent}}"  frameborder="0">
                                                    </iframe>
                                                </div>
                                                <div ng-switch-when="PPT" ng-class="{'marBot45':fullScreen==true}">
                                                    <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
                                                    <iframe id="pptViewer" ng-src="{{lessonContent}}" frameborder="0">
                                                    </iframe>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="left carousel-control {{carouselLeftBar}}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="ShowPrevLesson()">
                                        </span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
                                     <a class="right carousel-control {{carouselRightBar}}"
                                            role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right right-arrow"
                                                aria-hidden="true" ng-click="ShowNextLesson()"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                        </a>
                                </div>
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngSwitch', required by directive 'ngSwitchWhen', can't be found!